# Python lowercase list comprehension failing tests when it seems to be right?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, lowercase

I'm doing a Python course that involves completing numerous online questions, and the task seemed really simple (take a list of strings and convert it to lowercase). However, my code fails no matter what I try. I've tried list comprehension and loops, but to no avail - it just says failed test.
Here is the code below:

```
def lowercase(strings):
    """takes a list strings and replaces string with lowercase words"""
    strings = [x.lower() for x in strings]
    return strings   

strings = ['LOWER', 'CASE', 'SENTENCE']
lowercase(strings)
print(strings)
```

The part I am supplied is:

```
def lowercase(strings):
    """takes a list strings and replaces string with lowercase words"""


strings = ['LOWER', 'CASE', 'SENTENCE']
lowercase(strings)
print(strings)
```

So I'm only allowed to write code within the function that changes 'strings' to lowercase (I can write code under the doc string, but I can't modify anything else such as deleting those three lines of test code). Because their test declares strings and calls the function under my code, it seems to just overwrite anything I write! I feel like I'm going crazy as this is a beginner question and I can't make it pass the test. What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try print(lowercase(strings)).

Comment: Your function call isn't actually replacing the string. But you said that you can't modify the code outside the function. So you may need to perform an in-place change. Or make the `string` reference global inside the function

Comment: Veera Samantula - As already stated, I'm not allowed to modify the last three lines.

Comment: @Shaken_not_stirred. your test-case seems to require in-place modification or assigning to the global variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need only a minor change: modify the list in place using a slice assignment, rather than creating a new list. You then don't need to return it (in fact, the Python convention is to not do so).

```
def lowercase(strings):
    """takes a list of strings and replaces each with lowercase version"""
    strings[:] = (x.lower() for x in strings)
```

Comment: Does the generator expression automatically get cast to list?

Comment: kindall - Thank you, this is brilliant. I didn't think of taking a shallow copy of 'strings', but that works perfectly to produce the lowercase list.

Comment: @NChauhan more strictly speaking,  all items are consumed from the generator on the right hand side and inserted into `strings`.

Comment: [`list_ass_slice` calls `PySequence_Fast`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/listobject.c#L606), consuming the generator to populate a list (not `strings`), because it needs to know how many items it's going to receive. The genexp doesn't save any memory; a list comprehension would be more efficient.

Comment: N Chauhan - the generator is still a generator (it isn't cast as a list), but by assigning it a variable name (in this case 'strings') the generator was then called when strings was called.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the function you have makes a copy of `strings` inside of it, and returns the copy. Instead, you want to modify the list in place.

Here's one way you can do it:

```
def lowercase(strings):
    """takes a list strings and replaces string with lowercase words"""
    for i, x in enumerate(strings):
        strings[i] = x.lower()

strings = ['LOWER', 'CASE', 'SENTENCE']
lowercase(strings)
print(strings)
#['lower', 'case', 'sentence']
```

Instead of the list comprehension (which creates a new list), iterate over the indices of `strings` and modify each element.

Comment: pault - Thank you. This is another brilliant solution that works!

Answer (score 0):

With same List Comprehension code try this one

```
strings = ['LOWER', 'CASE', 'SENTENCE']
strings = lowercase(strings)

print(strings)
```